# Changing or removing a commit message on GitHub?

Tags: github, github-pages

I just made my first pull request on GitHub, but I want to change the commit message, or remove it outright. To clarify, I did this using the website, not the command line. Any assistance is helpful, I'm pretty new at this.

Answer (score 0):

You  just need to clone the repo locally and then add changes you want in the repo and finally commit with --amend  (*only if it is not merged*)

-To clone the repo

`git clone <your repo URL>`
This URL can be copied from the github

-Adding changes in repo files and/or commit message
`git add .`

`git commit --amend -m <your message>`

`--amend` lets you change the last commit (I.e you can add files and change the commit messages )

-Finally pushing the change to GitHub

`git push -f origin master`

`-f` or  `--force` let you replace the history of your remote repo(GitHub) with local history.

Comment: I tried cloning it, but it said 'repository not found'. What page exactly do I need to copy the URL of?

Comment: You need to get the URL of git repository from the little icon (clone or download button) in the top right corner on the GitHub page. Use HTTPS method and make sure there is `.git ` in the end of that URL :)

Comment: I cloned it... but it's not allowing me to change the last commit. I don't get it.

Comment: Follow the steps given above. And if you are getting any errors or some problem revert back here.